# How to get Facebook access token and User ID on iphone

Tags: iphone, facebook

I want to make a demo of using OAuth to get a facebook access token in a mobile app.
i have a button on the main view. After button is clicked, I use safari to open the facebook OAuth dialog. After logging in to facebook, I can't figure out how to get the access token and UserID.

Answer (score 0):

You need to spend some time reading the documentation on [how Facebook works with iOS](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/iossdk/). Specifically there is a whole documentation section [dedication to iOS authentication](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/iossdk/authentication/).

The way you are currently doing it with redirecting to Safari is not the preferred way of handling this as far as I know.

Comment: Hi mechanel. Link you send to me is invalid url

Comment: @DuongNguyenHai I'm not sure what you mean by invalid url.  Both of them work correctly for me.